# Nested Function scope chain in javascript

Tags: javascript

**I read these lines in "JavaScript The Definite Guide" and I am not able to understand why scope chain of inner function will be different each time function is invoked**

"In top-level JavaScript code (i.e., code not contained within any function definitions),
the scope chain consists of a single object, the global object.
In a non-nested function,
the scope chain consists of two objects.
The first is the object that defines the function’s
parameters and local variables, and the second is the global object.
In a nested function,
the scope chain has three or more objects.

It is important to understand how this chain
of objects is created.
When a function is defined, it stores the scope chain then in effect.
When that function is invoked, it creates a new object to store its local variables, and
adds that new object to the stored scope chain to create a new, longer, chain that
represents the scope for that function invocation.

This becomes more interesting for
nested functions because each time the outer function is called, the inner function is
defined again.
Since the scope chain differs on each invocation of the outer function,
the inner function will be subtly different each time it is defined—the code of the inner
function will be identical on each invocation of the outer function, but the scope chain
associated with that code will be different."

Comment: 404: Question not found.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to mark up the part that's a quote and separate it from your question. Please also clarify your question.

Comment: Done and thanx.

Comment: No, not done. Please click "edit" gaain and look at the toolbar, read the editing help, etc.

Comment: Sir, I am new to this site so not able to write question nicely but i will try. Sorry for the inconvenience .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call a function, you create a new scope for that invocation of the function.

Any variables defined (with `var`, function declarations, or as a named parameter) in that function are scoped to that function.

```
function foo (bar) { };
foo(1);
foo(2);
```

In the above, two scopes are created. In one of them, `bar` is `1` in the other `bar` is 2.

---

If a function is defined in another function, then it has access to the scope it was created in.

```
function foo (bar) { return function () { console.log(bar); } };
var foo1 = foo(1);
var foo2 = foo(2);
```

The function assigned to `foo1` has access to the scope where `bar` is `1`.

The function assigned to `foo2` has access to the scope where `bar` is `2`.